# Using a Query or Stored Procedure to Report on the differences between two tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I have created the following two tables:

`Table1`:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
PersonID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
JobRole varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_employee PRIMARY KEY (personid) USING INDEX
);
```

`Table 2`:

```
CREATE TABLE DBAteam
(
PersonID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
JobRole varchar(255) NOT NULL,
Location varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_dbateam PRIMARY KEY (personid) USING INDEX
);
```

The following is the trigger and stored procedure I'm using to populate the two tables:

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_trigger_test AFTER INSERT ON employees FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
p_procedure_test(:NEW.personid, :NEW.lastname, :NEW.firstname, :NEW.jobrole,           :NEW.location);
END trg_trigger_test;
/
```

Stored procedure:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_procedure_test 
    (
    i_personid  IN employees.personid%TYPE,
    i_lastname  IN employees.lastname%TYPE,
    i_firstname IN employees.firstname%TYPE,
    i_jobrole   IN employees.jobrole%TYPE,
    i_location  IN employees.location%TYPE
    ) AS
    --
  BEGIN
    --
    INSERT INTO dbateam 
    (
    personid,
    lastname,
    firstname,
    jobrole,
    location
    )
  VALUES 
    (
    i_personid,
    i_lastname,
    i_firstname,
    i_jobrole,
    i_location);
  --
END p_procedure_test;
/
```

I need to find a way in which I can create a stored procedure or query to show me the differences between the two tables

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling with this.

Comment: what database you use ? oracle,mysql,sql server ?

Comment: I would query your schema.  I'm assuming that a DBA is also an employee.  It may make sense for there to be some sort of a flag on employee, or let an employee take many roles rather than being a whole new table with duplicate fields.

Comment: do you want to populate the dbateam with dba employees everytime and dba employee is inserted in the employees table ?

Comment: I wanted to create a table for all the employees. Then create separate tables for all different types of employees.

Comment: On paper this seemed to make perfect sense, but I now realize my thinking may have been flawed.

Comment: Also if somebody could present a stored procedure for this solution, that would be great also. So in the future I know what to do if a similar situation presents itself.

Comment: Yes UpOne, that is exactly what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**In Oracle :**

```
SELECT * FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM table2
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM table2 t2
                    WHERE t1.some_key = t2.some_key )
```

**In Mysql:**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table2 )

UNION

SELECT * FROM table2 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table1 )
```

**In SQL SERVER**

```
select * from table1 
except
select * from table2
```